# PostgreSQL hstore & searching with Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sphinx, hstore

I have a Ruby on Rails 4.0 application and am using the PostgreSQL database management system.

My schema.db looks as follows:

```
  create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.hstore   "properties"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Record example:

```
<Item id: 1, title: "CASTROL", properties: {"type"=>"oil", "cars"=>"all"}>
```

Can I use Sphinx to search through PostgreSQL hstore keys?

Answer (score -1):

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :item, :with => :active_record do
  # fields
  indexes title, :sortable => true
  indexes "properties -> 'cars'", :as => :cars, :sortable => true
  indexes "properties -> 'type'", :as => :type, :sortable => true

  # attributes
  has created_at, updated_at
end
```

Comment: Your answer has shown up in the low quality queue. Please add an explanation as to how this answers the OPs question.